# Disable camera panning in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

If I am using the default camera control in SceneKit, is there a way to disable the two fingered pan function and leave the others as they are?

I want users to be able to rotate and zoom an object, but not move it at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sceneView already has a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached.
If you modify its maximumNumberOfTouches to be 1, you can disable the pan gesture.

```
for reco in sceneView.gestureRecognizers! {
    if let panReco = reco as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        panReco.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, I still had this problem in my project after all these years, and this brilliant answer finally fixed it out of nowhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, how would I apply this to the swiftUI View `SceneView()` ? Or would I need to setup UIViewRepresentable ?

Comment: @MadeByDouglas I guess so.

Answer (score 2):

No. You'll have to make your own camera and use gesture recognizers.